# Windows Azure Servicebus Token Provider was unable to provide token, but returned an empty message

Tags: c#, azure, queue, servicebus

When trying to receive a message from a Servicebus queue, an exception gets thrown about the Token Provider:

> The token provider was unable to provide a security token while accessing 'https://xyz-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net/WRAPv0.9/'. Token provider returned message: ''.

This only happens when my issuer and key are correct. When they are incorrect, the token provider returns a message describing what was wrong. I'll add the code to the post until where it goes wrong:

```cs
string user = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceBusUser"];
string key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceBusSecret"];

TransportClientEndpointBehavior securityBehaviour = new TransportClientEndpointBehavior(TokenProvider.CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider(user, key));

Uri uri = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", "xyz", queue);
Uri deadUri = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", "xyz", queue + "/$DeadLetterQueue");

if (readDeadly && allIsWell)
{
    IChannelListener<IInputChannel> deadChannelListener = messagingBinding.BuildChannelListener<IInputChannel>(deadUri, securityBehaviour);
    deadChannelListener.Open();
    IInputChannel deadInputChannel = deadChannelListener.AcceptChannel();
    deadInputChannel.Open();

    while (readDeadly && allIsWell)
    {
        FlexilineLogger.Log(logpath, "readDeadly");
        try
        {
            try
            {
                queueMessage = deadInputChannel.Receive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

And the Exception occurs at the Receive.
This worked yesterday like a charm, but today it keeps throwing the exception above.

Has anyone else encountered this and perhaps knows the reason for this exception?
Or does someone have a solution for this problem and would like to share it?

Thank you.

Comment: Just fell over this. Do es that still happen? I assume it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/piyushjo/archive/2011/09/27/azure-service-bus-working-with-the-appfabriclabs-account.aspx

seems to be the answer, though I'm trying to figure out how to do this in a worker role.